# Iimporting a certificate Java keystore

Tags: java, security, certificate, keystore

I always have to import a new certificate when ever I delete a server and create a new one for my webapplication.
cant the same certificate be used ?Tried using it but gives a PKIX error.

Server is localhost tomcat.Certificates have been imported in Cacerts.
Certificate is selfsigned.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be used. I used the same certificate on different tomcats. But please but your ceacerts into your java jdk/jre/lib/security/ 
and also create tomcat crt.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: i did create a certificate (.cer) also put it into cacerts.still it gives the same error.any specific problem as to why it happens..i also tried to use Djavax .but still gives an error.Ideally it should run.but dunno why here its not working.